# Using a variable inside -moz-linear-gradient breaks the style

Tags: css

I try to use custom variables inside my CSS.

Under **FireFox**: everything is okay.

Under **Google Chrome** or **Microsoft Edge**: it works pretty well on `linear-gradient` but not on `-moz-linear-gradient`

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/Bronzato1/pen/VwWBJjP?editors=1100

To show you the problem, I created the `first` class which works as expected and the `second` class with the usage of a variable inside `-moz-linear-gradient` breaks the style !

HTML

```
<div class="first red"></div>
<div class="second red"></div>
```

CSS

```
.red {
    --custom-color: #FF0000;
}
.first::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 19rem;
  height: 14rem;
  background: linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left; 
  /*FF*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, black 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.second::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  width: 19rem;
  height: 14rem;
  background: linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left; 
  /*FF*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce this issue, the CSS variable gradient appears to work correctly for me in Firefox v92. (E.g. [I see a gradient here](https://jsfiddle.net/1h9ktqd0/) on Firefox, do you not?)

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. Indeed it works well on Firefox but the problem is with Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your prefixed styles above the standard style, e.g.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(...) no-repeat bottom left;
background: linear-gradient(...) no-repeat bottom left;
```

Otherwise the browser will attempt to use the last valid style, which I believe causes problems since `background` is a combined style so you end up overwriting your `linear-gradient` with a `-moz-linear-gradient` that Chrome doesn't understand.

Working example:

```css
.red {
  --custom-color: #FF0000;
}

.first::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 19rem;
  height: 14rem;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, red 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background: linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.second::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  width: 19rem;
  height: 14rem;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background: linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="first red"></div>
<div class="second red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.red {
    --custom-color: #FF0000;
}
.first::before, .second::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 19rem;
  height: 14rem;
  background: linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, var(--custom-color) 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left; 
  /*FF*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(128deg, transparent 51%, black 53%, red 70%, transparent 72%) no-repeat bottom left;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.second::before{
  top: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Your implementation `fix` the red color for FireFox which is not what I want. On my sample I show a basic example (only red) but I'll need more colors (red, green, blue, yellow). That's why I need a solution with variables compatible with all browsers.